# Turn off enable calculation

Tags: excel, vba, properties, calculation

I have a workbook with a lot of different formulas and I have one worksheet in it called Map, that I need to not auto calculate, every time I enter new data into a different worksheet. I have the following VBA code below on this worksheet. The problem is I need to manually go to the Developer tab, Properties, EnableCalculation, and select False. When I do it this way, the code works perfectly. However when I close and re-open the workbook, the EnableCalculation in the Properties, has been automatically changed to True. I can't seem to come up with a code to turn this Property on this individual sheet only to False upon opening the workbook.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated. I am new to coding, like this is my first time trying to write a VBA code and its taken me days to just get what I have below. So the more descriptive the better. Thank you!

```
Sub docalc()
Dim oldCalc As Boolean
oldCalc = ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = oldCalc
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a module called `Sub Workbook_Open()` and add the line `ws.EnableCalculation = False` where ws is whichever worksheet you want to set the property for--for example `worksheets("Sheet4")` or `worksheets(4)`. The Workbook_Open() sub will run automatically every time the workbook is opened.

Comment: Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Map").EnableCalculation = False
Dim oldCalc As Boolean
oldCalc = ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = oldCalc
End Sub
Is this what you mean?

Comment: @BillyKuhn You can just do `Sub Workbook_Open()  
Worksheets("Map").EnableCalculation = False  
End Sub  ` but keep in mind it won't recalculate that worksheet until the value is marked as `true`. In what circumstances would you want it to recalculate?

Comment: I seemed to got it working now. The code I had was applied to a button so it would only recalculate when the button was clicked. That way, when I was working in other tabs and entering in data, this worksheet would not be recalculating every time I typed because it is all based off of way to many formulas.  When I just had the string, I was not getting the enable calculation property turned off, but by combining it, and using the button on opening, it solves my problem.

Comment: @BillyKuhn Glad to hear it. If you're satisfied with the solution, mark the question as answered and that will help the next person looking for this sort of solution.