# How to stop automatic pivot table calculation when opening excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm new here and have only a basic knowledge on VBA.

My struggle is:
I have a huge report with a big number of pivot tables. Some of them have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If Target = "PivotTable1" Then
       Call PTTransport
       
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that everytime I open the workbook it refresh and calculate all pivot tables related to this Call.

How can I stop to automatic start this code to run. My original need is to start this pivot table calculation when the target is updated only, not everytime I open the file.

Comment: Set `EnableCalculation` option to `False` in `Workbook_Open` Sub and set it back to `True` in `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856220/turn-off-enable-calculation) may help, I suppose.

Comment: the problem is that before the workbook_open runs, the private sub already triggered the pivot table re-calculation. I will try now the option to turn off when closing. I hope it works.